# Credentials for Member server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

So i am working on my member server right now and everytime I am adding accounts in security tab of a folder, I am asked for login name and password from the Domain Controller. How do select so I dont need to do this everytime? I am watching this video guide and the man there never need to fill in credentials on his member server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you logged on using a domain account?

From the symptoms it sounds like you may be logging on using a local account.